# Retrieve info in DLL assembly about calling assembly

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have created several DLL (.NET) libraries that are used in several projects. In these DLL libraries I want to know/retrieve which assembly (EXE) calls/uses the library, so if possible I want to know info like assembly name (EXE), strong name, version number, etc.

NB: Examples may be in C# or VB. I use both languages.

Comment: Are you looking for GetEntryAssembly? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.Reflection => Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() should do the job.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection for this task.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/The-Role-of-Reflection-in-VB-(NET).aspx